# Is the following an example of "currying"?

Tags: functions

> Is the following an example of "currying"? If so, can someone explain this to me like I am 5? I am a programmer, not a mathematician.

In andrew ng's machine learning class on coursera, he represents a function $$h_\theta(x) = \theta_0 + \theta_1*x_1 + \theta_2*x_2 \,\dots\, \theta_n*x_n$$ with `n` representing the number of inputs (`x`).

later in the course, he displays a sum of squared errors function as $$J(\theta) = \sum(h_\theta(x^i) - y)^2$$ with `x^i` denoting a superscript `i` and not an
exponent `i`. `i` denotes an index into `x`, and `x` is an input vector. but this doesn't make sense. my question is, if we were to actually do `h_theta(x^i)` and give the value of `x^i` as a parameter to `h_theta`, we would not have all the `Xs` (inputs) in `h_theta(x)` defined, only that particular input. (for example, `x^1=300` would translate to `h_theta(x) = theta_0 + theta_1*300 + theta_2*x_2... + theta_n*x_n)` This does not translate well. Can anyone help me understand this? Here is the link to the video that introduces this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q4GNLhRtZNc

Someone in irc told me this is currying. I asked if he could explain to me what exactly that is and I didn't understand his answer because it required knowledge of functions in the context of math, using notation I had never seen. Could someone explain this to a math noob?

Comment: So just randomly jumping forward in the video I landed at 2:05 where it is explained that $x_j^{(i)}$ is the value of the $j$th feature (otherwise known as $x_j$) in the $i$th training example. There is a reason why he used subscripts in one formula and superscripts in the other! Indeed $h_\theta(x^i)$ is a completely evaluated function of all $n$ components of the vector of inputs $x^i.$ Currying has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am putting more into your comments than is already there, but it seems to me that you are more comfortable with computing language than with mathematical language.

$x$ is not a single value, it is a "vector". But really, the "vector" nominclature is not all that appropriate even from a mathematical perspective, as he is not really exploring the vector properties of these numbers, but rather is just representing table entries. From a computing perspective, $x$ is an 1-dimensional array, whose elements are denoted by subscripts:
$$x_i \equiv \rm{x[i]}$$

$x$ refers to a single row of his table (not including the price, which is an output). The collection of all rows is an array-of-arrays. Let me denote this table array as $\rm T$. So for each $j$, $\rm T[j]$ is itself an array of length $n$. Then the $i$-th element of that array is $\rm T[j][i]$. This is what the superscript index is about. For each $j, x^{(j)}$ is the $j$-th row of the table. That is, $$x^{(j)} \equiv \rm T[j]\\x^{(j)}_i \equiv \rm T[j][i]$$

Since he is discussing cases where the number of inputs $n > 1$, your example of $x^i = 300$ doesn't make sense because $300$ is a single value, while $x^i$ is an entire array. $x^i$ has to have all the entries defined, not just one.

$h_\theta(x)$ is a function on arrays, not single values. In computing, you might see it defined as

```
 double hTheta(double[n] x) { ... }
```

Then to apply it to row $j$ of the table, you might see `hTheta[T[j]]`. That is what he means by $h_\theta(x^{(j)})$